Is there any way to show an image on top of an extruded polygon in maplibre-gl-js
I'm working with MapLibre and I'm trying to overlay an image on top of an extruded polygon, similar to the example below:

I've attempted to use the fill-extrusion-pattern property, but the image keeps repeating.
Does anyone have any suggestions on achieving this effect without the image repeating?
Thank you!

You can achieve this by using a combination of image and fill-extrusion layers.

Prepare the Image: Ensure your image is prepared and hosted in a way that can be accessed by your application.

Initialize MapLibre Map: Initialize your MapLibre map as usual.

Overlay the Image: Use a fill-extrusion layer to create the extrusion and an image layer to overlay the image on top without repeating.



Initialize the Map: Standard MapLibre map initialization.
Polygon Coordinates: Define the coordinates of your polygon where the image will be overlaid.
Fill-Extrusion Layer: Create the extrusion using a fill-extrusion layer.
Image Overlay: Load your image and add it as a raster layer on top of the polygon without repeating.

By specifying the exact coordinates for the image layer, you ensure that the image does not repeat and fits perfectly on top of your extruded polygon. Adjust the coordinates and other properties to fit your specific use case.
Example:


    // Define coordinates for the center of the map
    const centerLongitude = -74.0060; // Replace with your center longitude
    const centerLatitude = 40.7128; // Replace with your center latitude

    // Define coordinates for the polygon (replace with your actual coordinates)
    const coordinates = [
      [-74.007, 40.713], // longitude1, latitude1
      [-74.005, 40.713], // longitude2, latitude2
      [-74.005, 40.712], // longitude3, latitude3
      [-74.007, 40.712]  // longitude4, latitude4
    ];

    // Initialize MapLibre map
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'https://demotiles.maplibre.org/style.json', // Example style URL
      center: [centerLongitude, centerLatitude], // Set to your coordinates
      zoom: 15
    });

    // Wait until the map is loaded
    map.on('load', function () {
      // Add a source for the polygon
      map.addSource('polygon', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [coordinates]
          }
        }
      });

      // Add the fill-extrusion layer
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'polygon-extrusion',
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'source': 'polygon',
        'paint': {
          'fill-extrusion-color': '#888',
          'fill-extrusion-height': 20,
          'fill-extrusion-base': 0,
          'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.5
        }
      });

      // Add the image to the map
      map.loadImage('/mnt/data/UKmCUoED.png', function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;
        map.addImage('custom-image', image);

        // Add a layer with the image
        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'image-overlay',
          'type': 'raster',
          'source': {
            'type': 'image',
            'url': '/mnt/data/UKmCUoED.png', // Use the path to your image
            'coordinates': coordinates
          },
          'paint': {
            'raster-opacity': 1.0
          }
        });
      });
    });
  
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MapLibre Image Overlay Example</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@1.15.2/dist/maplibre-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@1.15.2/dist/maplibre-gl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>



